# Filling dynamic array from File

Tags: c

Hello i am having a problem with filling my array from a file. First time i run my nacitaj function it works great. But after i call it one more time the output values are crazy. Is there any way to tell the program to overwrite the values in suma[] after nacitaj function is called more than once?

```
int nacitaj(float *suma, int *k) {
FILE *fr;
int i=0;
int j=1;
int o=1;
char p[30];
j=*k;


if ((fr = fopen("FILE.TXT","r")) == NULL){
    printf("NULL\n");
}
else {
    while(feof(fr) == 0){
        fgets(p,30,fr);
        fgets(p,30,fr);
        fgets(p,30,fr);
        fgets(p,30,fr);
        fgets(p,30,fr);
        i++;
    }

    suma=((float*)malloc(i*sizeof (float))); 
    rewind(fr);

    while(feof(fr) == 0){
        fgets(p,30,fr);
        fgets(p,30,fr);
        fgets(p,30,fr);
        fscanf(fr,"%f\n", &suma[j]);
        fgets(p,30,fr);
        fgets(p,30,fr);
        j++;

    }

}
*k=j;
fclose(fr);
return suma;
}
```

MAIN

```
if(c=='N'){
            suma=nacitaj(suma,&k);
        }
```

I tried to do

```
suma=((float*)malloc(0*sizeof (float)));
```

in the beggining but it made it even worse.

Comment: Are you setting `k` to something decent before calling the function again ?

Comment: am i allocating 0byte of memory when i have i++ before allocating?
i appologize for int k... it has nothing to do with this part of program

Comment: @Toesmash Yes it does: `j=*k;`.

Comment: wow i totally did not see that... can i set k to 0 before filling the array?

Comment: You should set `k=0` before call your function in the second time. Do not forget to your code according to this.

Comment: Ok after several hours (thank to you) i fixed at least the nonsense numbers part... i set a new variable (int a=0)and where i was scannning numbers into the file I changed &suma[j] to &suma[a]. I have to still figured out how to re-allocate my array when calling my function second time.

Comment: If you can (requires a POSIX-2008 compliant system), use `getline()` to read textual input. Why? Because `getline()` allocates a suitably sized buffer *for you*. This removes all the headaches connected to the fixed 30 character size limit which you impose on your user with `fgets(p,30,fr)`. Such limits are generally not just limits, they are sleeping bugs which will eventually bite you.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to still figured out how to re-allocate my array when calling
>   my function second time.

You already are re-allocating the array when calling the function again, with the very same statement (which, besides, has unlovely many parentheses and type casts).

```
    suma=((float*)malloc(i*sizeof (float)));
```

What you may be looking for is how to de-allocate the array when it's no longer needed.

```
    free(suma);
```